# How to send key press to terminal in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, mplayer

I'm working on a Python script to use my old rotary phone as input device for a webradio. The dialer is connected by GPIO to a Raspberry Pi3 and launches mplayer to play a station when I dial '1'. 
When I launch the script form terminal (by ssh) it works fine: I get all kinds of information about the channel, tracks being played etc.. Also, when I press '9' or '0' on my keyboard the volume goes up and down.

Next thing I want to do is to control the volume by dialing '2' (volume up) or '3' (volume down), from the script(!).

I've tried several libraries like xdotools etc., but they all expect a display I guess. Nothing seems to work, so far.

Is it possible at all? Anyone any pointers or solutions? I would be very grateful, this thing has cost me all day and I didn't progress a bit.

This is the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
from time import sleep
import subprocess

#GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

c=0
last = 1

def count(pin):
    global c 
    c = c + 1

def play_radio(dial):
    if dial == 1:
        subprocess.call("mplayer -nocache -afm ffmpeg http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/SLAM_MP3.mp3",shell=True)
    if dial == 2:
        #HERE'S WHERE THE VOLUME MUST GO UP BY KEYPRESS '0'
    if dial == 3:
        #HERE'S WHERE THE VOLUME MUST GO DOWN BY KEYPRESS '9'

GPIO.add_event_detect(15, GPIO.BOTH)

while True:
    try:
        if GPIO.event_detected(15):
            current = GPIO.input(15)
            if(last != current):
                if(current == 0):
                    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.BOTH, callback=count, bouncetime=10)
                else:
                    GPIO.remove_event_detect(18)
                    number = int((c-1)/2)
                    print(number)
                    play_radio(number)
                    c = 0                 


                last = GPIO.input(15)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: You could use `keyboard` to detect keypresses? How you implement that is up to you https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: Tried it, but can't get it to work....

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: You could try `curses`, however I think that you're implementing it wrong.. (i.e. you shouldn't have your check for key press **within** the if statement, the key press event should be the if statement itself)

Comment: I'm not trying to detect a keypress, I'm trying to simulate one. You are right about the way I'm implementing it: there's something wrong there. In another script I tried out keyboard.press_and_release() and that works...
My problem is somewhere in the While True loop. When I dial '1' mplayer starts to play the radiostation. But it seems the while loop stopped, because no other dial actions have any effect.

Comment: If you think the `while` loop has stopped, I suggest adding in a print function to see if it has stopped. So inside your `while True:` and in a `print('running')` so you can see it does stop running. If it does, it may be because `subprocess.call` blocks any continuing python execution until the the process called is finished running.

Comment: If you're not sure if something is happening or not, add a `print` to where something should be happening, always helpful

Comment: Did just that and yes: the while loop stops after calling the play_radio function. If I don't call this function, but print the number variable, the loop keeps running....

Comment: Found it: subprocess.call blocks the Python code. Guess I'll have to use subprocess.Popen...